# What Drupal theme is this site using?

Tags: theming

Does anyone know which Drupal theme these sites are using? I am interested in purchasing a copy.

1. http://www.kidsgardening.org/
2. http://www.garden.org/

Comment: See this discussion on how to identify what theme a Drupal site is using: https://groups.drupal.org/node/313863  Please note that your question as written is off topic for this site.  Check the rules for more information.  Asking "How can I tell what theme a Drupal site is using?" would be much more likely to be accepted.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying themes in external sites

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kidsgardening.org is using a custom theme named "Kids Gardening" that is a subtheme of [Zen](https://drupal.org/project/zen).

http://www.garden.org is not a Drupal site.